# How long does it take to open a link once clicked?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have an element that disappears after clicking on it

```
document.getElementById("").style.display = "none";
```

But it is also a link.

If I do not put a delay on it disappearing, then the link does not work and does not open before the element disappears.

After some testing I found that the minimum number of milliseconds I have to delay the javascript function for, for the link to still be opened is 50.

My question is, is there a set reason for it being this number? Is this the same for all devices and all browsers, or is it specific?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that illustrates the issue? Seems to work for me without timeout: https://jsfiddle.net/heqr6e72/

Comment: @trincot Your fiddle displays an alert, it doesn't link to another page. That seems to make a difference.

Comment: I would not count on that working across browsers or devices. I wouldn't even count on it working in the next release of the same browser.

Comment: Why do you need to make the link disappear? When you link to a new page, the whole page is replaced.